# How to read matrix from text file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a text file in the same folder as my matlab code called `matlab.in`, its contents are

```
training_set = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
```

How do I read this matrix into a variable called `training_set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text file contains an executable Matlab statement.  You could, probably even should, rename it to something like `training_set.m` (the `.m` suffix is important) and simply 'read'  it from the command line by executing it.  On my machine the 'command'

```
>> training_set
```

generates the response

```
training_set =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
```

and, hey presto, the variable `training_set` is now safely ensconced in your workspace.

Now congratulate yourself for having written your first (?) Matlab *script*, reward yourself with a visit to the documentation to review this important topic.

Answer (score 0):

First, open it using `fopen(...)`:

```
fid = fopen('matlab.in');
```

Second, read the line from the file and close the file again, since you don't need it anymore:

```
content = fgetl(fid);
fclose(fid);
```

Third, evaluate the string read from the file:

```
eval(content);
```

If you wanted to suppress the output, you might either want to add  a semicolon at the end of the text file or instead use:

```
eval(strcat(content,';'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file1.txt: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
           10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80

    [fileID,errmsg] = fopen('file1.txt')
    val= textscan(fileID, '%u8')
    z = transpose(cell2mat(val))
    vec = transpose(reshape(z, [8 2]))

...

Gives you 
vec =

  2×8 uint8 matrix

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.